# Add new record inline in x-editable bootstrap yii

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, x-editable

Please let me know how to add new row functionality to x-editable inline edit table.

I need the table to be completely inline editable adding new records, editing, deleting etc., without navigating to a modal dialog or new page.

I have made a **yii x-editable table** inline editable but need to know how to add new record on click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to achieve the same in my project. I found the following in the official x-editable documentation:

> Creating new record is a bit problem for editable interface because primary key (record id) is unknown and in-place-editing has no related object on backend. In that case editable will store new value inside and will not submit anything to server until you do it manually .This is default behavior when pk option is empty and send='auto'. To submit manually several editable fields there is submit api method.

Here is the link: [x-editable documentation](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#newrecord)

It shows you an example also how to handle such case.